# Casting object to ValueTuple

Tags: c#, .net, casting, tuples

Given the OnNavigatedTo method of the class Page (UWP)

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Parameter != null)
        {
            var o = (ValueTuple<object, object>) e.Parameter;
            Content = (UIElement) o.Item1;
            this.DataContext = o.Item2;
        }

        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
```

I want to cast the **e.Parameter** (of type object) to a `ValueTuple<object, object>`.

The parameter carries the instance I want to past as part of a `Frame.Navigate` call like this:

`Frame.Navigate(typeof(SomePage), (view, viewModel));`

The cast should work. It's supposed to be safe because I think that `ValueTuple<X, Y>` should be able to be casted to `ValueTuple<object, object>`, right?

However, it throws an **Invalid Cast Exception**.

What's wrong with the casting?

How can I cast from a reference of type `object` that contains an instance of a tuple, to a typed reference to a tuple?

## Additional info

The exact exception thrown is this:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.ValueTuple`2[System.Object,Reflight.Gui.ViewModels.FlightGalleryViewModel]'
>   to type 'System.ValueTuple`2[System.Object,System.Object]'.'

e.Parameter.GetType() outputs this:

> {Name = "ValueTuple`2" FullName = "System.ValueTuple`2[[System.Object,
>   System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Reflight.Gui.ViewModels.FlightGalleryViewModel,
>   Reflight.Gui.ViewModels, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]"}
>       Assembly: {System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e}
>       AssemblyQualifiedName: "System.ValueTuple`2[[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Reflight.Gui.ViewModels.FlightGalleryViewModel,
>   Reflight.Gui.ViewModels, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"
>       Attributes: Public | Sealed | Serializable | BeforeFieldInit
>       BaseType: {Name = "ValueType" FullName = "System.ValueType"}
>       ContainsGenericParameters: false
>       CustomAttributes: Count = 2
>       DeclaredConstructors: {System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo[1]}
>       DeclaredEvents: {System.Reflection.EventInfo[0]}
>       DeclaredFields: {System.Reflection.FieldInfo[2]}
>       DeclaredMembers: {System.Reflection.MemberInfo[19]}
>       DeclaredMethods: {System.Reflection.MethodInfo[14]}
>       DeclaredNestedTypes: {System.Reflection.TypeInfo.<get_DeclaredNestedTypes>d__22}
>       DeclaredProperties: {System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[2]}
>       DeclaringMethod: '((System.RuntimeType)e.Parameter.GetType()).DeclaringMethod' threw an
>   exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>       DeclaringType: null
>       FullName: "System.ValueTuple`2[[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Reflight.Gui.ViewModels.FlightGalleryViewModel,
>   Reflight.Gui.ViewModels, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]"
>       GUID: {4a04084c-cb2b-378d-aa9c-a77abd9ba77e}
>       GenericParameterAttributes: '((System.RuntimeType)e.Parameter.GetType()).GenericParameterAttributes'
>   threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>       GenericParameterPosition: '((System.RuntimeType)e.Parameter.GetType()).GenericParameterPosition'
>   threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>       GenericTypeArguments: {System.Type[2]}
>       GenericTypeParameters: {System.Type[0]}
>       HasElementType: false
>       ImplementedInterfaces: {System.Type[7]}
>       IsAbstract: false
>       IsAnsiClass: true
>       IsArray: false
>       IsAutoClass: false
>       IsAutoLayout: true
>       IsByRef: false
>       IsByRefLike: false
>       IsCOMObject: false
>       IsClass: false
>       IsCollectible: false
>       IsConstructedGenericType: true
>       IsContextful: false
>       IsEnum: false
>       IsExplicitLayout: false
>       IsGenericMethodParameter: false
>       IsGenericParameter: false
>       IsGenericType: true
>       IsGenericTypeDefinition: false
>       IsGenericTypeParameter: false
>       IsImport: false
>       IsInterface: false
>       IsLayoutSequential: false
>       IsMarshalByRef: false
>       IsNested: false
>       IsNestedAssembly: false
>       IsNestedFamANDAssem: false
>       IsNestedFamORAssem: false
>       IsNestedFamily: false
>       IsNestedPrivate: false
>       IsNestedPublic: false
>       IsNotPublic: false
>       IsPointer: false
>       IsPrimitive: false
>       IsPublic: true
>       IsSZArray: false
>       IsSealed: true
>       IsSecurityCritical: true
>       IsSecuritySafeCritical: false
>       IsSecurityTransparent: false
>       IsSerializable: true
>       IsSignatureType: false
>       IsSpecialName: false
>       IsTypeDefinition: false
>       IsUnicodeClass: false
>       IsValueType: true
>       IsVariableBoundArray: false
>       IsVisible: true
>       MemberType: TypeInfo
>       MetadataToken: 33554856
>       Module (System.Reflection.MemberInfo): {System.Private.CoreLib.dll}
>       Module: {System.Private.CoreLib.dll}
>       Name: "ValueTuple`2"
>       Namespace: "System"
>       ReflectedType: null
>       StructLayoutAttribute: {System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute}
>       TypeHandle: {System.RuntimeTypeHandle}
>       TypeInitializer: null
>       UnderlyingSystemType: {Name = "ValueTuple`2" FullName = "System.ValueTuple`2[[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Reflight.Gui.ViewModels.FlightGalleryViewModel,
>   Reflight.Gui.ViewModels, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]"}

Comment: Please show a [mcve] rather than just the receiving part. You claim "the cast is safe" but it sounds like you're almost certainly passing in a different type. Please also include the result of `e.Parameter.GetType()`.

Comment: The type is not *what* you expected... `FlightGalleryViewModel` <> `object`... You would have seen this is you inspected what `e.Parameter` was, this is a debugging issue here.

Comment: `var o = (ValueTuple<object, FlightGalleryViewModel>) e.Parameter;`

Comment: Right - so it's exactly as described in my answer. It's *not* a `ValueTuple<object, object>`. If you know the *real* type, cast to that. If you don't, use `ITuple`. Or change the producing code to actually produce a `ValueTuple<object, object>`.

Comment: I cannot do that cast. The page is supposed to be used to host any UIElement and the ViewModel can be any object.

Comment: @JonSkeet Is there a good way to pack a UWP app and post it here other than creating a GitHub repo especially for this issue? Thanks.

Comment: No, but you don't need to - a console app can show the exact same thing. The fact that it's UWP is irrelevant to why you can't cast. Fundamentally you need to accept that you will *not* be able to cast a `ValueTuple<object, FlightGalleryViewModel>` to `ValueTuple<object, object>` though. So either you need to stop trying to do that cast, or change the code that produces the tuple to produce a genuine `ValueTuple<object, object>`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I just figured out before reading this. The solution has come changing code that creates the tuple. Please, see the auto-answer I've posted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SuperJMN Note that changing the code creating the tuple has been in my answer right from the start...

Comment: @JonSkeet That's right. But you at the very first second I didn't consider change the caller because I thought it was perfect, and that a ValueTuple<Y, X> should inherently be convertible to ValueTuple<object, object>. After a bit of thiking (you drove me to the right track) I finally saw it. I upvoted your answer, and I will accept it as the answer, but I'll keep mine just in case. You're is more explicative :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How can I cast from a reference of type object that contains an instance of a tuple, to a typed referece to a tuple?

You have to cast to the *right* tuple type. You're casting a `ValueTuple<MyClass, object>` to a `ValueTuple<object, object>`, and those are different types.

This works fine, for example:

```cs
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        object obj = ("foo", "bar");
        // Casting to the right type works... but a cast to
        // ValueTuple<object, object> would fail.
        var tuple = (ValueTuple<string, string>) obj;
        Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item1); // foo
        Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item2); // bar
    }
}
```

If you *want* a `ValueTuple<object, object>` you can do that, of course:

```cs
object myTuple = ((object) instance, new object());
```

If you want to refer to *any* value tuple, you may (depending on the framework you're targeting, unfortunately) be able to use [`ITuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.ituple?view=netframework-4.8):

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        object obj = ("foo", 10);
        var tuple = (ITuple) obj;

        for (int i = 0; i < tuple.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tuple[i]); // foo then 10
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Jon, that's right, but in my real world scenario I receive the tuple as an object. What are my options?

Comment: @SuperJMN: We don't know what you're trying to achieve, so it's hard to give any advice. I can only answer the questions you've asked.

Comment: Find out what type of object you receive. Use your debugger.

Comment: OK, the scenario is the OnNavigatedTo method of Page (UWP). I'm sending it a tuple as parameter. The parameter is of type (object), but I really know it's a ValueTuple<object, object> containing the view and the viewmodel of the Page.

Comment: @SuperJMN: I suspect it's not *actually* a `ValueTuple<object, object>` though, otherwise a cast to `ValueTuple<object, object>` would succeed. What does `GetType()` return? I've added an example of using `ITuple` in my answer, in case that's helpful. But if you really want to cast, you need to use the right type.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've update the OP with the real code. Let me inspect the exact exception message. I'm adding it to the OP in a second. Thanks in advance, mate.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by being explicit and calling `Frame.Navigate` like this.

`frame.Navigate(typeof(NavigationPage), ((object)content, (object)vm));`

This way, the casting works.

Comment: The realm of boxing and unboxing *later*... You will have to cast these again when you want to use them.